# How exactly does Python's .replace() works?

Tags: python, replace

I was trying to replace two different characters `@` and `.` in a string with one character `|` . When I assign the replacing variable to the same variable, the replacing of `@` and `.` to `|` works, but using different variable, it only replace dot to `|`. May I know what's the reason causing the difference?

Using same variable:

```
email = input("Please enter your email address : ")
for x in ('@','.'):
     email = email.replace(x,'|')
print(email)
```

Output:

```
Please enter your email address : sdf@sadfs.com
sdf|sadfs|com
```

Using other variable:

```
email = input("Please enter your email address : ")
for x in ('@','.'):
     temp_email = email.replace(x,'|')
print(temp_email)
```

Output:

```
Please enter your email address : sdf@sadfs.com
sdf@sadfs|com
```

Comment: In the first example you run the 2nd replace on the output of your 1st replace. In the second example you run it twice on your starting variable `email`, causing only the last replace to show in `temp_email`. This is not something related to how `replace` works

Comment: The replace() method returns a copy of the string where the old substring is replaced with the new substring. The original string is unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first loop, you're overwriting `email` both times, when the loop executes

```
email = email.replace(x,'|')
```

In the second loop, you store it in `temp_email`, so `email` isn't overwritten. When we execute

```
temp_email = email.replace(x,'|')
```

the first time, `x='@'`, so `temp_email` becomes `sdf|sadfs.com`. Then the second time it's executes, `x='.'`, so `temp_email` becomes `sdf@sadfs|com`. This is because both times it's editing `email` to create `temp_email`, but `email` hasn't been changed!

Answer (score 0):

At first execution of your (for) loop will turns @ to '|'
Temp_email = sdf@sadfs.com

But email is un changed

so
email = sdf@sadfs.com

At second execution of your (for) loop will turns . to '|'

Then

Temp_email = sdf@sadfs|com

Then it prints

Here is your Expected Code

```html
<script src="//onlinegdb.com/embed/js/i-fTLYV9M?theme=dark"></script>
```

Please vote up bro

Comment: Click the Run Code Snippet button